# Ensure parallel reduction of numpy array operation mapping to repeated position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reduction

Is there a way for numpy to ensure that an array operation mapping to repeated positions undergo a reduction, i.e. they are both performed on the result of each other?

```
a = numpy.zeros([4], int) # [0 0 0 0]
b = numpy.arange(0, 8)    # [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]

positions = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]

a[positions] += b         

# desired result: [0 + 1, 2 + 3, 4 + 5, 6 + 7]
# actual result: random crossover between [0, 2, 4, 6] and [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

as you can see both element 1 and 2 of b map to position 1 and so on, I need to make sure that += adds both, whereas by default it looks like it can randomly add 1 or 2 to zero at the same time, *then* store the result twice, which is in turn the result of only one of the operations

Comment: I always get [1, 3, 5, 7] as result. What version are you on?

Comment: it doesn't matter, it's one of the wrong combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there are repeated indices, the behavior of in-place addition in a numpy array is undefined.  To ensure the behavior that you want, use `numpy.add.at`.  (All numpy "ufuncs" have the [`at` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html).)

For example, here are your arrays:

```
In [21]: a
Out[21]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])

In [22]: b
Out[22]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

In [23]: positions
Out[23]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Use `numpy.add.at` to accumulate the values:

```
In [24]: np.add.at(a, positions, b)

In [25]: a
Out[25]: array([ 1,  5,  9, 13])
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!